# SendPostRequest without a payload in Codeceptjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, codeceptjs

I've been tinkering with codeceptjs and I wanna know if there is a way to do a sendPostRequest without a payload.

Here's my sample:

```
Scenario('Sample', async (I) => {
  var resp,
  args = {
  "TABLE_ID": 748,
  "STATUS" : 5
};

var reqHead = {
  'Accept'    : 'application/json',
  'User-Agent': 'Unirest Node.js'
};

var urlSamp = 'table/sample?TABLE_ID=' + args.TABLE_ID + '&STATUS=' + args.STATUS, args;

I.haveRequestHeaders(reqHead);
resp = await I.sendPostRequest(urlSamp);
resp = resp.body;
resp = JSON.stringify(resp);

I.say(resp ? resp : "Err: " + resp + " -- Msg: System may not be currently running.");
});
```

So, is this line correct?

```
resp = await I.sendPostRequest(urlSamp);
```

Actually, I've already done the line of code above, however it resulted into an error.

I've also tried the following below:

```
resp = await I.sendPostRequest(urlSamp, '');
```

Or...

```
resp = await I.sendPostRequest(urlSamp, null);
```

And...

```
resp = await I.sendPostRequest(urlSamp, {});
```

However, none of the above worked. 
Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've already done this in Postman, and I was able to get the expected result. However for codecept, I'm receiving a different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
resp = await I.sendPostRequest(urlSamp);
```

Above line alone is enough and actually works without the payload.
My main issue was not the codeceptjs, nor the payload, but rather my system itself.